# Magento - can't find - $this->getForm()->toHtml()

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, adminhtml

In my store when dealing with orders in the admin section via `Admin > Sales > Orders > Edit Shipping Address` the "State" field is missing for some reason.

I finally found the file in the backend located

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/address/form.phtml
```

But when I try to add the field it only has this php code:

```
<?php echo $this->getForm()->toHtml() ?> in line 41.
```

Where can I edit the `getForm()`?

Is it a file someplace, or in the database, or in the configuration settings somewhere?

---

### UPDATE - Still stuck been 4 hours :(

I see in the database the "adminhtml_customer_address" and changed values around - flushed cache and nothing changed....

Database screenshot

[image]

Admin screenshot mission "state/region" missing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The form uses the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Address_Form`.

This can be found by searching for where the template is used in the code base or by turning on the template hints via the admin config.

The block mentioned mainly extends the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Address` and in this block you can find the function `_prepareForm` which is actually used to add the elements to the form element.

I think the part that might be breaking for you is the addition of field elements with the line `$this->_addAttributesToForm($attributes, $fieldset);`.

What this should do is add all the attributes needed to the form.

Have a look in the table `customer_form_attribute` for the form code `adminhtml_customer_address` and see what attributes are set to be shown in this form. If state or region is not set then try adding that attribute here and see what happens.

Comment: Yea but the order itself has the "State" visible, but when click on "edit" shipping address or billing address.. the "state" select field is missing entirely from the editable options...?

Comment: is the order placed via admin or frontend because the forms are different.

Comment: Front End, and I understand some countries can have the "state" turned off.. but this is all from the united states and there is a state labeled on the order

Comment: The two forms are different so they can easily have different options show, either by choice or mistake. Check out the database table mentioned and see what the difference is between the frontend and admin

Comment: I took a screenshot of the "customer_form_attribute" in the database.. i see a lot of info not sure what to look at... http://oi57.tinypic.com/1602ypf.jpg

Comment: Maybe this helps http://oi60.tinypic.com/2wpm6fo.jpg

Comment: There is no "state" in the attributes for "adminhtml_customer_address" there is two region_id's though

Comment: no action? see updated on top question

Answer (score 0):

The template is actually a renderer for the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Address` that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Abstract`.
This last one has a method called `getForm` that looks like this:

```
public function getForm()
{
    if (is_null($this->_form)) {
        $this->_form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->_prepareForm();
    }

    return $this->_form;
}
```

This means that if the class has the _form member populated it returns is, if not, it creates an instance of `Varien_Data_Form` and returns it.
The form is manipulated in the `_prepareForm` method

Answer (score -1):

I found all the element display in the form in the eav_attribute table in the database. Hope it helps.